# Check dangerous permissions every time

Tags: android

> If your app needs a dangerous permission, you must check whether you have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires that permission.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
(in the case of API 23 and above)

Does it mean:

1. The permission dialog will popup every time that operation is about to be performed to grant permission.
2. Just to ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() (programmatically) if permission is granted, if so then no permission dialog will popup.

or something else...

**Why I need this answer:**

I have a service that works in background multiple times a day(requesting location) NON-CONTINUOUSLY, lets say 3 times/day, does this mean that runtime permission dialog has to show up 3 times a day whenever my service is going to perform its work -or- it has to show up only the first time my service starts and then it checks programmatically (only) the remaining 2 times if permission was granted ? (same question above reformed here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this mean that runtime permission dialog has to show up 3 times a day whenever my service is going to perform its work

Probably not.

> it has to show up only the first time my service starts and then it checks programmatically (only) the remaining 2 times if permission was granted ?

Probably not.

The quote from the documentation means that you need to call `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` before you try performing an operation that needs a runtime permission (`dangerous` permissions). This does not display any UI. It merely lets you know whether or not you hold the permission.

If you do not hold the permission, you will to request the permission from the user before you will be able to do whatever it is that you are trying to do. *That* needs to be performed from an activity or fragment, using `requestPermissions()`.

In your case, before you schedule the background work (`WorkManager`, `JobScheduler`, etc.), use `requestPermissions()`, and only schedule that work if the user grants you your desired permission(s).

However, it is possible that the user will *revoke* the granted permissions. That is why your background work will need to call `checkSelfPermission()`. If that indicates that you do not hold the permission, you will need to raise a `Notification` that leads the user to your UI, where you can once again `requestPermissions()`.

Comment: Nice detailed answer exactly what I wanted to here :) (my first question in stackoverflow , it says avoid commenting with "thanks" what do I say ? anyway, thank you for the answer @CommonsWare)

Answer (score 0):

It means you need to call checkSelfPermission each time, and make sure the user didn't remove your permission (because if they did the action will fail, either with an error return or an exception).  However if that returns false, the only way to get permission is to show the dialog.  Or you can just not do whatever you were planning to.